# Appropriate location for my application's cache on Windows

Tags: python, windows

My application caches some data on disk.  Because the cache may be large, it should not be stored on a network drive.  It should persist between invocations of the application.  I have a mechanism for the user to choose a location, but would like the default to be sensible and "the right thing" for the platform.

What is the appropriate location for such a cache?  Is there an API for determining the appropriate location?  How do I call it from Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#User_management_variables. Anything that's under the users directory is good. If its for all users, then it should be: %ALLUSERSPROFILE%. If its for a specific user, make sure the permissions are right.

Check out MSDN for more info about other Windows Versions. Environment variables can vary from systems to systems.

Comment: what I'm reading is that, for normal users, the %ALLUSERSPROFILE% folder is read-only. Not sure but that's what people are saying...

Answer (score 3):

The standard location for Windows application to store their (permanent) application data is referenced by the `%APPDATA%` (current user) or `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%` (all users) environment variables. You can access them using, e.g. (only rudimentary and not very elegant error checking!):

```
import os
app_path = os.getenv("APPDATA") + "\\MyApplicationData"
try:
    os.mkdir(app_path)
except WindowsError:
    # already exists
```

Now you have your own directory for your app.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number a places you can put your application files in Windows.  [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) shows a list (this enum is .Net specific but most of the special folders are standard on Windows in general).  Basically you'll need to decide if you need a cache per user, only for the local machine, per application or shared, etc.

I don't have much experience with python so I cannot specifically help with how to get these paths, but I'm sure someone more knowledgeable here can.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the [`tempfile`](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html) module provides what you need. It uses the Windows Temp directory (which probably is not on a network drive) but you can specify a directory if you want to. Also for security reasons this module should be the right tool - if you use `tempfile.mkstemp()` the file is readable and writable only by the creating user ID.

Oh. I see you have just edited your question and that you need file persistence between invocations of the app. Then `tempfile` is not that ideal (even though you could choose not to delete your cache between invocations).

Answer (score 1):

The [`wx.StandardPaths`](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.StandardPaths-class.html) module contains methods that return various standard locations in the file system and transparently tries to do "the right thing" under Unix, Mac OS X, and Windows.

Answer (score 1):

A handy package for this is [appdirs](https://github.com/ActiveState/appdirs), which support Windows and most other operating systems. For example, to create a cache directory for "MyApp" version 1.0 published by "Author" is:

```
import os
from appdirs import user_cache_dir

dirname = user_cache_dir("AppName", "Author", "v1.0")
# C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Author\AppName\Cache\v1.0

# create it, if it doesn't exist
os.makedirs(dirname, exist_ok=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the app have any preferences, settings or options that the user can specify? If so, add an option where the user can specify the location of the data, with a default of the current Windows temp directory.

There's always a chance they may not have enough space on the drive with the temp directory, and would need to use a different drive/directory.